# Firestore Java Get fields ​of documents within collections without knowing the name of them

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm programming an activity that through firebaserecyclerview gets all posts of an user from the following **firestore** structure:

```
--- posts (collection)
         |
         --- uid (documents)
              |
              --- userPosts (collection)
                    |
                    --- postId (documents)
                    |     |
                    |     --- title: "Post Title"
                    |     |
                    |     --- date: September 03, 2018 at 6:16:58 PM UTC+3
                    |
                    --- postId (documents)
                          |
                          --- title: "Post Title"
                          |
                          --- date: 08/06/2021
                          |
                          --- description: "this is the description of the post"
                          [...etc]
```

This is my incorrect query sketch:

```
Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        .collection("post").document(uidVisit).collection("userPosts")
        .limit(1000);
```

Obviously, the above query is wrong for what I want to get, because that query stops at selecting the contents of *userpost* which are nothing more than the ids of the posts that I actually have to fetch:

[image: effect of the previous query]

Instead, I want to take all the contents of the various user posts but the only problem is that I do not know the post id (because they are all different). Is there a way then to get the posts from that firestore structure that I inserted at the beginning of the post? I hope I have made you understand my problem

In case it can help you, I leave my complete code:

Full Code:

```
EditText searchEt;
    TextView ustxt;


    private RecyclerView findUsersList;  //fidnfirendlist

    private String str = "", uidVisit = "";
    private DatabaseReference usersRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_visualizza_post);
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        uidVisit = intent.getStringExtra("uidVisit");

        findUsersList = findViewById(R.id.usersSearched);

        searchEt = findViewById(R.id.txt_ricerca);
        ustxt = findViewById(R.id.name_text);
        findUsersList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("post").document(uidVisit).collection("userPosts")
                //.orderby
                .limit(50);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<GetInfoPost> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<GetInfoPost>()
                .setQuery(query, GetInfoPost.class)
                .build();

        FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<GetInfoPost, FindFriendsViewHolder> firestoreRecyclerAdapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<GetInfoPost, FindFriendsViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FindFriendsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull GetInfoPost model) {
                holder.txtTitoloInPost.setText(model.getTitle());
                holder.txtData.setText(model.getdate());
                Picasso.get().load(model.getUrlImage()).into(holder.imgPost);
                holder.txtDescrizione.setText(model.getDescription());
                holder.txtTag.setText(model.getGenre());
               // holder.txtLikenmb.setText(model.getLike());
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public FindFriendsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.post, parent, false);

                return new FindFriendsViewHolder(view);
            }
        };

        findUsersList.setAdapter(firestoreRecyclerAdapter);
        firestoreRecyclerAdapter.startListening();






    }

    public static class FindFriendsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView nameInPost, txtData, txtTag, txtTitoloInPost, txtLikenmb, txtDescrizione;
        ImageView img_profinPost, imgPost;
        RelativeLayout cardView;



        public FindFriendsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            nameInPost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameInPost);
            txtData = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtData);
            txtTag = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTag);
            txtTitoloInPost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitoloInPost);
            txtLikenmb = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtLikenmb);
            txtDescrizione = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescrizione);

            img_profinPost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_profinPost);
            imgPost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgPost);


            cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_viewR);

        }
    }
```

GetInfoPost class:

```
package com.conta.pophome;

public class GetInfoPost {

    String title, urlImage, genre, valutation, date, description, like;

    public GetInfoPost() {
    }

    public GetInfoPost( String title, String urlImage, String genre, String valutation, String date, String description, String like) {
        this.title = title;
        this.urlImage = urlImage;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.valutation = valutation;
        this.date = date;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getLike() {
        return like;
    }

    public void setLike(String title) {
        this.like = like;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String title) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getUrlImage() {
        return urlImage;
    }

    public void setUrlImage(String urlImage) {
        this.urlImage = urlImage;
    }

    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(String genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public String getValutation() {
        return valutation;
    }

    public void setValutation(String valutation) {
        this.valutation = valutation;
    }

    public String getdate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setdate(String date) {
        date = date;
    }
}
```

Updated query:

```
Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("post/" + uidVisit + "/userPosts")
                .limit(1000);
```

Comment: You say: *problem is that I do not know the post id (because they are all different)* You don't know all the post IDs or the IDs of the users? Not in the first solution you don't know the IDs of posts. So to understand better, you need all the posts of all users from the database?

Comment: @AlexMamo For now I want to view only the posts of a user, so I know the user id, but I don't know the id of the various posts. So I don't know how to structure the query

Comment: What is the value of `uidVisit` in your query?

Comment: @AlexMamo That variable represents the user id of the user we need to get posts and  I get it with get extra because I pass the value from another activity by clicking on a button 'view post of the user in question'

Comment: Are you sure it's the correct one, the one from the database `ra3!...3ccr`?

Comment: @AlexMamo What you are talking about (ra3! ... 3ccr) is the post id. the user id is before it (see the photo of the firestore facility)

Comment: Oh, ya, sorry, my mistake. Is it `dwqZ....0Of2`?

Comment: @AlexMamo exactly

Comment: Please also edit your question and add the content of your `GetInfoPost` class.

Comment: @AlexMamo Ok, I added the getinfopost class in question

Comment: If you try to log `model.getTitle()` inside your `onBindViewHolder` class, do you get something printed out?

Comment: @AlexMamo Now it works even if the description is not displayed in the textview. I tried using the query that I now add at the bottom of the question

Comment: It looks to me that it's the same query as before. But good to hear that it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call document.getId() to get document id.

```
Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("post").document(uidVisit).collection("userPosts")
                //.orderby
                .limit(50);

  
           query.get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Check here to know about adapter (https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-android/firestore/readme/)

Comment: I put my compelt code at the bottom of the post, so I was wondering how I could use getid () to fix my problem

Comment: you are asking me to make the query dynamic because to get each post I have to do each query different because the value I take with getid () always changes, so I was wondering how to run each query and get the fields every time

Comment: To get all document ,store your all document id in list (uidVisit).then run for() loop to get all inner document.@pophome